# What is Cognitively Stimulating in User Experience goal means?

Tags: ux-field

I am an undergraduate from Computer Science major. Recently my lecturer ask his class to study about specific topic in user experience goals before the class next Monday. I read the ppt online and found that one of the user experience goals is **cognitively stimulating**. My country doesn't use english as primary language, and I have trouble in understanding what is "cognitively stimulating" means. As far as I search, here is what I conclude : "cognitively stimulating means a software / product must stimulate user brain to thinking and remembering". Is there any problems / mistake with my conclusion? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks before.

edit : added screen shot
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of that ppt slide?

Comment: edited @MarkBubel

Comment: I think it doesn't make much sense. Cognitive stimulation in Pyschology is a therapy for people with Alzheimer or senile dementia. In terms of pure semiologic meaning, almost anything (good or bad) could be cognitively stimulating. For example, the process of affordance discovery is a cognitive stimulation. If someone jumps to you with a knife in a dark alley, you'll have a hell of a cognitive stimulation as well. So it could mean extremely different things (ambiguity anyone?), but I assume your lecturer means the first option (the affordance example)

Comment: In day to day language it means -  'mentally stimulating'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognition is involved in how we perceive information (visual, auditory, touch), process it, and make decisions based on it how to act.

It involves **attention, working memory, long-term memory, decision making** etc. So if you use your long-term memory to recall some memory your cognition is stimulated.

Generally, persons cognition is always stimulated because you always use your attention and working memory. If your cognition is not stimulated you cannot experience anything. Your cognition creates the experience.

So your objective is ambigious, and you should ask to specify what kind of cognitive stimulation they mean?